# Webpack - module not loaded with dynamic import

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, babeljs

I have two nearly identical environments:

- the default index.html page created by webpack plugin which inject the bundle (works fine)
- injecting the script into another page via Google Tag Manager (not working)

The error is being thrown here in the webpack code:

```
// Execute the module function
modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
```

This module is `undefined` although it is being fetched over the network perfectly fine.

The correct value for `moduleId` is being called however it is not present in the `modules` array.

This is happening specifically with modules being loaded dynamically using `import()`.

Full error:

```
demo:8613 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (demo:62)
    at Object.349 (main.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (demo:62)
    at demo:8604
```

I am at a wits end, have tried:

- various webpack versions
- various loading methods eager, lazy (clarification: using `eager` removes the problem but my chunk is loaded in one!)
- naming patterns

My stack nodejs8, vuejs2, express4, webpack 4.9.2 running on Google App Engine.

EDIT:
When I load my script in the broken scenario - I make an API call to a route on the server which serves the script into a script src.

Any idea??

Comment: "injecting the script into another page via Google Tag Manager (not working)" -  which order had you put all js files?

Comment: The script has a single entry point in both scenarios main.bundle.js